# How to remove elements of a list where its string contains sub strings from another list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string like this:

```
var str = "DAVID CORPORATION"
```

then i have a list of substrings that i dont want in the str.

```
var describers = new List<string> {"CORP", "INC", "LTD", "TECH", "ENGINEER", "LLC","MICROELE"};
```

then i split the str here into a list:

```
var strList = str.Split(' ').ToList();
```

now i want to remove all items of that list that contains the substrings in describers. I found this way to do it a million times all over the internet.

```
strList.RemoveAll(x => describers.Contains(x));
```

This does not work because all it does is check if the describers contain the whole word of the strList. I need it to work in reverse.

This doesn't work but its an algorithm of how i want it to work.

```
strList.RemoveAll(x => x.Contains(describers.Any()));
```

> Cannot convert from 'bool' to 'string'

of course, but how to i remove the item in strList that contains the substring item from describers.

..and only in a linq.lamba. I am trying to stay away foreach/for/do loops.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do the following using `Any`:

```
strList.RemoveAll(x => describers.Any(d => x.Contains(d)));
```